# How to fix migrate Laravel error 'PDOException and PDO::__construct'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pdo

I'm trying to execute the `php artisan migrate` command to create a table in phpmyadmin

But its showing error of

> "could not find driver"

I have made the `php artisan serve` and it worked

```
 'mysql' => [
                'driver' => 'mysql',
                'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
                'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'testdb'),
                'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
                'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxx'),
                'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
                'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
                'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
                'prefix' => '',
                'prefix_indexes' => true,
                'strict' => true,
                'engine' => null,
                'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

```
 DB_CONNECTION=mysql
 DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
 DB_PORT=3306
 DB_DATABASE=testdb
 DB_USERNAME=root
 DB_PASSWORD=xxxx
```

**This is the error showing in the command line:**

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver 
   (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 
    testdb and table_name = migrations)

  at C:\AppServ\www\laravel2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("could not find driver")
      C:\AppServ\www\laravel2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=testdb", "root", "xxxx", [])
      C:\AppServ\www\laravel2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
```

it's expected to show **"tables created successfully"** and also created in phpmyadmin

Comment: try to hit composer dump-autoload, php artisan config:clear

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the mysql is running on your machine if you're using homestead mysql port might be 33060 ..

to clarify if mysql is running open the terminal on mac or linux or command line on windows and write 
`mysql -u root`
if you got the error that mean the mysql is not running.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the php-mysql driver for PHP, you can check it by executing `php -i | grep mysql`
If you are missing it you have to install it considering your system type, for example if you were working on a php7.2 system on ubuntu, you should do:
`sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysql`

Answer (score 0):

Change in `config/database.php` file according to this:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

Check here : [Link](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/database.php#L59-L60)

Open the `.env` file and edit it. just set up correct database credentials

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=            // Your Database Name
DB_USERNAME=           // Your Database Username
DB_PASSWORD=          // Your Database Password, If no password is set then just clear it
```

After `.env` edit, must be clear cache: `php artisan config:cache`